# Passing Multi Checkbox Value int FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Am trying to pass a Multi Checked Values into a PHP file that creates a PDF file.

Here my HTML code for the form:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Radiography (RT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Radiography (RT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Ultrasonic (UT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Ultrasonic (UT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Liquid Penetrant (PT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Liquid Penetrant (PT)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Magnetic Particle (MT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Magnetic Particle (MT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Visual (VT)" /></td>
    <td valign="middle">Visual (VT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Leak (LT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Leak (LT)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Eddy Current (EC)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Eddy Current (EC)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Infrared &amp; Thermography (I&amp;T)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Infrared &amp; Thermography (I&amp;T)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Acoustic Emission (AE)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Acoustic Emission (AE)</td>
</tr>
```

Here I use some validation and pass the values to my variable:

```
var checkBoxes=document.getElementsByName("afchek[]");

var booleanResult=false;
for(var i=0;i<checkBoxes.length;i++){
    if(checkBoxes[i].checked){
    booleanResult=true;
    break;
}
}

if(booleanResult==false){
    showError($afchek);
ok = false;
}
```

And here I'm passing my values to another php file that creates a pdf file:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'pdf/create_ASNT.php',
data: 'afname=' + $afname.val() + '&affname=' + $affname.val() + '&afdob=' + $afdob.val() + '&afage=' + $afage.val() + '&afgender=' + gender + '&afresaddress=' + $afresaddress.val() + '&afresmobile=' + $afresmobile.val() + '&afresemail=' + $afresemail.val() + '&afstat=' + $afstat.val() + '&afmobile=' + $afmobile.val() + '&afemail=' + $afemail.val() + '&afchek[]=' + checkBoxes + '&afenroll=' + $afenroll.val() + '&aftimecontact=' + $aftimecontact.val() + '&page1=ASNT-NDT-form.php',
success: function(){
    $afsuccess.fadeIn();
    $aferror.fadeOut();
}
```

Here I'm retrieving the query string values:

```
$afname=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afname"]);
$affname=ucfirst($_REQUEST["affname"]);
$afdob=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afdob"]);
$afage=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afage"]);
$afgender=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afgender"]);
$afresaddress=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afresaddress"]);
$afresmobile=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afresmobile"]);
$afresemail=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afresemail"]);
$afstat=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afstat"]);
$afmobile=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afmobile"]);
$afemail=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afemail"]);
//our problem here
$afchek=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afchek"]);
$afenroll=ucfirst($_REQUEST["afenroll"]);
$aftimecontact=ucfirst($_REQUEST["aftimecontact"]);
```

Now I could not print the values that I just passed from that file. I tried all the below things...

```
for($i=0;$i<count($afchek);$i++) {
    //    $selected_colors=$selected_colors . $colors[$i] . " , ";
$pdf->Cell(54, 0, $afchek[$i]);
}

$acco = count($afchek);
$pdf->Cell(54, 0, $acco);

$acco = count($_GET["afchek"]);
$pdf->Cell(54, 0, $acco1);

foreach($_GET["afchek"] as $valuer) {
$pdf->Cell(54, 0, $valuer);
}
```

Please can someone help to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but here is the working example: This will print the value you have submitted in your PHP file. Also try to use jquery instead.

```
<form action="formaction.php" id="form">
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Radiography (RT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Radiography (RT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Ultrasonic (UT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Ultrasonic (UT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Liquid Penetrant (PT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Liquid Penetrant (PT)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Magnetic Particle (MT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Magnetic Particle (MT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Visual (VT)" /></td>
    <td valign="middle">Visual (VT)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Leak (LT)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Leak (LT)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Eddy Current (EC)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Eddy Current (EC)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Infrared &amp; Thermography (I&amp;T)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Infrared &amp; Thermography (I&amp;T)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input style="margin-top:0px; cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox" name="afchek[]" value=" Acoustic Emission (AE)" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left:4px;">Acoustic Emission (AE)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Here is how you submit the form and it will alert the value you have submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").on("submit",function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           postdata = $('#form').serialize();
           $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'formaction.php',
             data: postdata,
             success: function(res){
                alert(res);
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is your PHP file: Which return whatever has been submitted through the form and alert it alert on success of  your ajax request.

```
<?php 
    //formaction.php
    $afname=$_POST["afchek"];
    foreach ($afname as $key => $afname) {
       echo ucfirst($afname);
    }
?>
```

Now you can use this value the way you want.

Demo link: http://dharmeshpatel.net/core_reporting_api/test.php

Hope that helps. Not exactly the way you wanted but you will get an idea.

Comment: Thank you Dharmesh, that's quite helpful for me, but i somehow manage to do in different way, jus by using javascript itself..

Comment: Yap... have done it.. can you help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647661/post-upload-file-ajax?noredirect=1#comment32717064_21647661

Comment: It sounds like you are not passing the file name through the Ajax request. In ajax do something like: var file = $("input[name=file]").val(); and pass that with data = postdata + '&filename=' + file, and in your php file access file name $filename = $_POST['file'] and then split the string using split or explode function to get the file name. Hope this helps. Check the demo link I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST supper global variable instead.

e.g.

```
ucfirst($_POST["afname"]);
```

or, try to serialize data and and pass that to your php file.

something like:

```
$("#Your_Form_ID").on("submit",function(){
   postdata = $('#Your_Form_ID').serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'pdf/create_ASNT.php',
     data: postdata ,
     success: function(res){
         $afsuccess.fadeIn();
         $aferror.fadeOut();
     }
 });
```

In your PHP file:

```
    $afname=ucfirst($_POST["afname"]);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you.. but it jus returns [object NodeList].. i dono... is there anything that i have left..?